# How can I loop through the values in react of a tuple(solidity)

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I have a function in my smart contract returns tuple and I want to return all the values to display on my react application, I used Promise.all to get back all the arrays but I got an error saying the ***data.map*** is not a function

console.log(data) returns all the arrays stored inside the tuple in the smart contract.

```
// fetchsubscribersData
  async function fetchsubscribersData() {
    const data = blockchain.smartContract.methods.fetchAllsubscribers().call();

    const items = await Promise.all(data.map( async i => {

      let item = {
        subscriber: i.subscriber,
        start: i.start,
        nextPayment: i.nextPayment,
        activated: i.activated
      }  

      return item;
    }));

    console.log(items);
    setSubscribersData(items);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the returned tuple is an object and not an array, you must use `Object.values` if you want to map through the returned values.